# I am having issues connecting to an Amazon RDS instance from an EC2 server, can connect from EVERYWHERE else

Tags: amazon-ec2, rds

I know there are other similar questions on the site, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I have an RDS instance set up. We run our site on an EC2 instance.

I know `MySQL` works on the EC2 instance, because our current `MySQL` database is run on a different non-RDS server, and everything works fine.

I can connect to the RDS instance through `MySQL` workbench (I've approved my public IP address to connect).

I can connect to the RDS instance via `phpMyAdmin`, which is installed on the EC2 server.

However, I cannot connect to the RDS instance using PHP/MySQLi.

```
DEFINE ('DB_USER', '**user**');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '**pass**');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '*************.rds.amazonaws.com');



if($dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)){

    //DB connected, do nothing

}

else {

    echo 'Connection error';
    echo mysqli_error();
    exit();

}
```

I'm getting no error output, nothing. It just echoes "Connection error".

I have the EC2 instance and RDS sharing a security group (although I can only edit inbound rules, not outbound, is this weird?), and have the EC2's public elastic IP allowed on the RDS security settings.

I'm lost!

Comment: Have you allowed the security group to access its own 3306 port? Your EC2 instance will be using an internal AWS IP to connect, not its Elastic IP.

Comment: I added access for all IP's (0.0.0.0) for the 3306 port, just to try it out... still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Replace `localhost`, `mysql_user` and `mysql_password` with your credentials.

*OR*

```
//conection:
mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```